# SQL Server for Saas - Best approach

Tags: sql-server, performance, saas

Say we have a large customer base, each customer can have a large amount of data. In SQL Server what is the best approach to handle this?

Would it be giving all records a new field to identify the customer?

Create a new database for each customer?

Some other option?

Thanks for your help

Comment: saas means there is some kind of middleware between the database and the client , unless you are providing the database server as a service directly. if so it makes sense to have one database per client.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx). Your options are:

- Separate Databases
- Shared Databases, Separate Schema
- Shared Database, Shared Schema

I strongly recommend going through the article to get the details on each, since there are just too many variables to consider, and rightfully so the article does not end up recommending one or the other since *you* must pick one base don your specific case.

Since is written in 2006 it does not consider [Azure Federations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh597452.aspx) which are a special case of `Shared Database, Shared Schema` approach but with built-in scale out provided by the Federations mechanism.

Also a search on stackoverflow and on dba.stackexchange for 'multi-tenant sql server' will reveal a plethora of previous discussions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [partitiondb](http://www.partitiondb.com/). they give the best solution for your case.

Look at their [saas example](http://partitiondb.com/saas-example-general-overview/). As you can see, you have one gatedb and multiple dbs for each customer. it's like an object-oriented concept for databases. they also support dbs on different servers.